# Next JS Home page Rendering Incorrectly with MUI

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

## Current Issue

I've been seeing the landing page on my web app rendering with lines ever since I attempted to add a custom MUI theme. What exactly is the issue with my code?
I'm actually following some of the official repo guidance from github: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/material-ui-nextjs

---

[Page render issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fcZj.png)
This is how I'm adding the theme:

##### EmotionCache

```
//utils/EmotionCache.jsx
'use client';
import * as React from 'react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from 'next/navigation';
import { CacheProvider as DefaultCacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';

// Adapted from https://github.com/garronej/tss-react/blob/main/src/next/appDir.tsx
export default function NextAppDirEmotionCacheProvider(props) {
  const { options, CacheProvider = DefaultCacheProvider, children } = props;

  const [registry] = React.useState(() => {
    const cache = createCache(options);
    cache.compat = true;
    const prevInsert = cache.insert;
    let inserted = [];
    cache.insert = (...args) => {
      const [selector, serialized] = args;
      if (cache.inserted[serialized.name] === undefined) {
        inserted.push({
          name: serialized.name,
          isGlobal: !selector,
        });
      }
      return prevInsert(...args);
    };
    const flush = () => {
      const prevInserted = inserted;
      inserted = [];
      return prevInserted;
    };
    return { cache, flush };
  });

  useServerInsertedHTML(() => {
    const inserted = registry.flush();
    if (inserted.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    let styles = '';
    let dataEmotionAttribute = registry.cache.key;

    const globals = [];

    inserted.forEach(({ name, isGlobal }) => {
      const style = registry.cache.inserted[name];

      if (typeof style !== 'boolean') {
        if (isGlobal) {
          globals.push({ name, style });
        } else {
          styles += style;
          dataEmotionAttribute += ` ${name}`;
        }
      }
    });

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {globals.map(({ name, style }) => (
          <style
            key={name}
            data-emotion={`${registry.cache.key}-global ${name}`}
            // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: style }}
          />
        ))}
        {styles && (
          <style
            data-emotion={dataEmotionAttribute}
            // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: styles }}
          />
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  });

  return <CacheProvider value={registry.cache}>{children}</CacheProvider>;
}
```

The following is the theme registry:

##### ThemeRegistry

```
//utils/ThemeRegistry.jsx
'use client';
import * as React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import NextAppDirEmotionCacheProvider from './EmotionCache';
import { themeOptions } from './theme';

export default function ThemeRegistry({ children }) {
  return (
    <NextAppDirEmotionCacheProvider options={{ key: 'mui' }}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={themeOptions}>
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        {children}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </NextAppDirEmotionCacheProvider>
  );
}
```

Lastly, the theme is injected into the layout:

##### Layout

```
//layout.js
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import ThemeRegistry from "./utils/ThemeRegistry";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Soul Senshi",
  description: "An online commerce store for custom rugs.",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ThemeRegistry>
          <Navbar />
          {children}
        </ThemeRegistry>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

This is the custom theme I am trying to utilize:

#### Theme

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const themeOptions = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
    primary: {
      main: '#1976d2',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#ff5722',
    },
    background: {
      paper: '#101012',
      default: '#0e0e0e',
    },
  },
});
```

### Some background:

- I've created a nextjs 14 app via `npx create-next-app` and initialized with `/app` directory (no /src) as well as using regular Javascript and enabling app routing (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing)/
- I chose to use MUI for my web app.

Can't quite seem to see what the issue is? I'm fairly new to nextjs and MUI so any help is appreciated.

The issue is coming from the Theme Registry I am using and possibly the client/server rendering for the current layout.